# Verification of an Entity–relationship model (for a software)

Tags: database, database-design, entity-relationship

I am designing the database of a company which distribute computer hardware between some companies. This database must contain all the information about the stock and will be accessed by a software.

I have made an entity-relationship model for my design. I would like to have some opinions about my design (I only had a one month class about databases, which is very short :/).

Here is an image of my ER model : http://i.gyazo.com/55c87a11a5b7f91a5a686d22ff01480b.png

[image: ER model]

And here are the explanations of my ER-model and my software :

**With the software**, the user should be able to see :

- How much categories of hardware there are (keyboard, printer, ...) ;
- The condition of each hardware (broken, new, ...) ;
- A history, which will list all the rentings made by the company and will include these informations : the date the hardware was rent, the company whom it was rent to,  the person who received the hardware in that company ;
- Where a hardware is (in the company's stock, at another company...)

**For the ER-model** :

- I put the brand and the design as primary key for each hardware. The ID for the `UC` and the `Laptop` will be used for the gibus number (concatenation).
- I have the feeling that one of the two entities : `Type of Hardware` / `Hardware` have to be deleted, correct or not ?
- I have put the condition of each hardware in a relation because the condition can change between two rentings, correct or not ? (new entity needed ?)
- An equipement can be rent in three places : `stock`, `others` and `departments` (the "companies"). It’s easy to understand what is the meaning of stock and departments but I have created the entity `others` to say if the computer hardware can be broken and it is in reparation (being repaired) or it can be rent.

With this ER model, could I make all the features of my software I have described ?
Thanks in advance (and sorry for my poor English).

Comment: Try to think how will you join Laptop, RAM etc. to Type_Hardware. That should show the main flaw in your current design. In your next  try fill in the joining logic (that is - foreign keys)

Comment: I have created the entity " Type_Hardware " to know easily how many types of hardware I have when I will ask my database, maybe I'm wrong or it's just useless :/